# How to find the weight of the most expensive diamond In R

Tags: r

I know max(diamonds$price) is the way to find the price of the most expensive one.
I do not know how to find its weight

Comment: `diamonds[which.max(diamonds$price),]` returns row that has maximum price.

Comment: Which weight in `diamonds` dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diamonds$weight[diamonds$price == max(diamonds$price)]
```

Meaning, extract vector `weight` from data.frame `diamonds`, filtering at the rows where `price` is equal to the max `price`.

Answer (score 1):

```
> df <- data.frame(price = c(1, 2, 3), 
                   weight = c(10, 5, 2))

> df
  price weight
1     1     10
2     2      5
3     3      2

> df[which.max(df$price), ]$weight
[1] 2
```